# Is Django-REST-framework stateless?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

According to REST API principles:

***Stateless – Each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request, and cannot take advantage of any stored context on the server. Session state is therefore kept entirely on the client.***

But `django-rest-framework` stores `tokens` in database (in `authtoken_token` table) and I delete a `token` to `logout` a user.If `token` is stored in server,is it really stateless?
Or am I understanding it wrong?

Thanks for answering!
[image: authtoken_token table]

Comment: the principle is referring to the client, every API stores data in a DB, not only tokens,
the principle says that the server should not guess aby data about the request.